# How to modify my below regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex `/\{([^\{\}]+)\}/` which looks for text in the **inner most** `{}`.

It matches any text inside innermost `{}`.

But now, i have a new requirement that, it should only match text between `{}`, when it is a loop.

That is it should preceded with either `for(.*)` or `while(.*)` and `do`.

How to modify my regex to match only if it is preceded by the above?

**Note:** My original regex's purpose shouldn't break.

Javascript solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
var match = code.match(/(?:(for|while|do)\s*\([^\{\}]*\))\s*\{([^\{\}]+)\}/);
```

If `match` isn't null, it will contain

- at index 1 either `for` or `while`
- at index 2 your inner loop content

Comment: mate what about `do`?

Comment: If you want to add `do`, use `/(?:(for|while|do)\s*\([^\{\}]*\))\s*\{([^\{\}]+)\}/`

Comment: Mate edit your answer, otherwise there is a chance that someone might downvote for not matching do

Comment: mate it worked. Will accept your answer in 5 minutes :)